# What does "limited success" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The tension between these two armies will grow. Some MPs will try, with **limited success**, to use the Article 50 debate to shape Mrs May’s negotiating position. A summer vote on the “Great Repeal Bill”, formally revoking the legislation that took Britain into the European club in 1973 (but also incorporating all current EU legislation into British law), will be another showdown.

Does it mean the success is improbable or is very insignificant?

Answer (score 1):

*with limited success* simply means that even though they will try to succeed, they will not be able to. In other words, they will fail. Their attempt to succeed will be limited. They might be able to win small battles, but the overall outcome for them will be failure.

Comment: so simply saying, they have no chance?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: @jackbang Not quite "no chance", but that their attempts will have very little effect - Mrs May will probably not change her negotiating position, and if she does it will only be by a very small amount.